# Task type in a IBackgroundTask class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, async-await

I want to do

```
async Task DoSomething()
{
   await SomeAsyncAPI();
}

async void Run()
{
   await DoSomething();
   DoAnother();
}
```

but Task type is not allowed in IBackgroundTask class. I want DoAnother() run after DoSomething completed.

Comment: What is wrong with what you're currently doing?

Comment: That is error because Task type is not allowed in IBackgroundTask class

Comment: not allowed in the class, which inherit from IBackgroundTask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the awaitable [`IAsyncAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows.foundation.iasyncaction) and [`WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsAsyncAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.asasyncaction(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IAsyncAction DoWorkAction()
{
    return DoWorkAsync().AsAsyncAction();
}

internal async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}

public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
   var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
   try
   {
      await DoWorkAction();
      DoAnother();
   }
   finally
   {
      deferral.Complete();
   }
}
```

For `Task<T>`, use `IAsyncOperation<T>`:

```
public IAsyncOperation<string> DoMoreWorkAction()
{
    return DoMoreWorkAsync().AsAsyncOperation();
}

internal async Task<string> DoMoreWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "Hello";
}

public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
   var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
   try
   {
      await DoMoreWorkAction();
      DoAnother();
   }
   finally
   {
      deferral.Complete();
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `taskInstance.GetDeferral`?

Comment: Another question please. How to do if `DoWorkAsync` is `Task<T>`

Comment: IAsyncOperation<T> was not allowed :(

Answer (score 3):

To use asynchronous methods with WinRT command-style events (including `IBackgroundTask.Run`), you need to use deferrals:

```
async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance instance)
{
  var deferral = instance.GetDeferral();
  try
  {
    await DoSomething();
    DoAnother();
  }
  finally
  {
    deferral.Complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Error at `async Task DoSomething()`